# Restrictions on my Schengen visa

Tags: visas, schengen, italy, denmark

I got a Schengen visa from Italy recently. It’s a multiple-entry visa, but on the top right it shows `-(D-EE-P)`, which I assumed is a restriction on entering Denmark, Estonia and Portugal. Am I right? And assume I wanted to visit Denmark, is it still legal if I enter via Italy (from within the Schengen area) rather than from the UK as they don’t ask me to show passport in the former.

Here is how it looks like:

[image]

Comment: D is Germany, I believe.

Comment: I also think D is for "Deutschland" = Germany in english.

Comment: I don't know if it is a restriction, but is then it won't matter which way you enter it will still be a violation. Your question is like asking if it's legal to sneak into a movie theater through the fire escape since they won't check your ticket on that route.

Comment: That's a really weird set of restrictions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a Limited Territorial Validity visa (LTV).

It seems that you cannot visit Germany, Estonia and Portugal (Denmark would be DK), no matter how you intend to enter these countries, from the Schengen area or from outside.